# Can we change Default directory name "Acme" to any other?

Tags: php, symfony

I just want to know can we change the Default directory structure i.e Bundle inside a Bundle like that and default Bundle directory Acme to something else.

Comment: You could, but then you would also have to change all the references to Acme everywhere else in the code (and file names, etc.).  Probably easier to just build your new bundle from scratch.

Comment: Useless but informative about the choice Acme name : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

Answer (score 0):

`Acme` is just a dummy vendor name. Replace it with your own when creating your own bundles.

> can we change the Default directory structure i.e *Bundle inside a Bundle*

What do you mean with 'bundle inside a bundle'? You want to create a AcmeDemoBundleFooBundle? No, that isn't possible.

---

As said in the comments. If you want to rename a bundle vendor, you need to do this manually. There is no script/command for that. (sidenote: The PHP grammar is much to flexible to write a good refactoring tool, that's why it don't exists or don't work)

You don't only have to rename the vendor name, you need to make sure all configuration is correct and uses the new vendor instead of `Acme`. [This doc article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html) is talking about removing bundles, but it can also be used as a checklist for savelly removing the bundle on a safe way.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply, but i have gone little bit ahead of creating 2-3 bundles now its possible to change Acme or instead of doing it manually , is there any specific command that can be used.

Comment: @rvd no, there is no command for that. You need to rename those yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's the only way of doing it... But it's not to hard, I think.

Comment: yes your are right in that way we can remove the bundle ,but just wanted to confirm that any way/command that can change Acme name to anything else ... Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Esy, delete your folder "Acme" with its content. Then though terminal call

```
php app/console generate:Bundle --namespace="Main\DefaultBundle
```

And you will get "Main" instead of "Acme"

Also you need clear appKenrel and other config files from your old configurations.